# How to disable arrows in insert mode VIM

Tags: vimrc, original-vim

I want to disable my VIM-arrows in VIM, to get used to move the cursor using hjkl. I have tried a lot of different approaches found on this forum, however, i can't seem to disable the up and down buttons in 'Insert Mode'.

Heres my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
" alternatively, pass a path where Vundle should install plugins
"call vundle#begin('~/some/path/here')

" let Vundle manage Vundle, required
Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'

" All of your Plugins must be added before the following line
call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required
" To ignore plugin indent changes, instead use:
"filetype plugin on
"
" Brief help
" :PluginList       - lists configured plugins
" :PluginInstall    - installs plugins; append `!` to update or just :PluginUpdate
" :PluginSearch foo - searches for foo; append `!` to refresh local cache
" :PluginClean      - confirms removal of unused plugins; append `!` to auto-approve removal
"
" see :h vundle for more details or wiki for FAQ
" Put your non-Plugin stuff after this line


" Removes preview window in YCM.
set completeopt-=preview

" Set clipboard to system clipboard
set clipboard=unnamedplus

" Enable pathogen
execute pathogen#infect()

" F# syntax on .fsi files. (.fsx and .fs are supported automaticly by plugin)
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.fsi set syntax=fsharp

" Set numbers on side.
" 
set number

" Disables arrow keys.
" Remove newbie crutches in Command Mode
cnoremap <Down> <Nop>
cnoremap <Left> <Nop>
cnoremap <Right> <Nop>
cnoremap <Up> <Nop>

" Disable Arrow keys in Insert mode
inoremap <Up> <Nop>
inoremap <Down> <Nop>
inoremap <Left> <Nop>
inoremap <Right> <Nop>
" Remove newbie crutches in Normal Mode
nnoremap <Down> <Nop>
nnoremap <Left> <Nop>
nnoremap <Right> <Nop>
nnoremap <Up> <Nop>

" Remove newbie crutches in Visual Mode
vnoremap <Down> <Nop>
vnoremap <Left> <Nop>
vnoremap <Right> <Nop>
vnoremap <Up> <Nop>
```

Arrow remapping is found in the bottom of .vimrc. Alongside inoremap, i have tried imap and this solution:

```
 noremap  <Up> ""
 noremap! <Up> <Esc>
 noremap  <Down> ""
 noremap! <Down> <Esc>
 noremap  <Left> ""
 noremap! <Left> <Esc>
 noremap  <Right> ""
 noremap! <Right> <Esc>
```

Found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548932/how-do-i-disable-the-arrow-keys-in-insert-mode.

Rn everything but Up and Down in 'Insert mode' is disabled.

Keyboard layout: Danish, Ubuntu 18.04
Vim: 8.0.1453

Comment: What's the output of `:verbose imap <Up>` after you open Vim?

Comment: Copy pasted:
 <Up>        * pumvisible() ? "\<C-P>" : "\<Up>"
        Last set from ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe/autoload/youcompleteme.vim
As far as i understand, YCM (autocompleter) is mapping <Up> after I'm calling noremap <Up> in .vimrc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [discussed in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/21318/how-to-disable-arrows-in-insert-mode-vim/21319#comment38362_21318), YouCompleteMe is overwriting your mapping with its own.

Normally, you can overwrite a setting that a plugin has made by using the [`.vim/after`](https://www.vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#load-plugins) directory but in this instance, YouCompleteMe is actually creating the mapping even later on, via an [autoload function](https://www.vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#autoload).

You might like to [check the YouCompleteMe documentation](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#options) to see if it's possible to stop it doing so. At a guess, it's the `g:ycm_key_list_select_completion` and `g:ycm_key_list_previous_completion` options you'll need to change.

Otherwise, you could try recreating *your* mappings [whenever you enter insert mode](https://www.vimhelp.org/autocmd.txt.html#InsertEnter):

```
augroup SeriouslyNoInsertArrows
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertEnter * inoremap <Up> <nop>
  autocmd InsertEnter * inoremap <Down> <nop>
augroup END
```

Or, if you want to continue using the arrows in YCM's autocomplete menus, you might prefer something like (untested):

```
augroup SeriouslyNoInsertArrows
  autocmd!
  autocmd InsertEnter * inoremap <expr> <Up> pumvisible() ? '<C-P>' : ''
  autocmd InsertEnter * inoremap <expr> <Down> pumvisible() ? '<C-N>' : ''
augroup END
```

Comment: This script (1st) works flawlessly! I will test 2nd script in a minute, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: I modified second Script to include: autocmd InsertEnter * inoremap <expr> <Down> pumvisible() ? "\<C-N>" : "". It worked!

Comment: @OliverBak Glad I could help! I updated the answer to correct the oversight.